# Fibonacci sequence and quadratic equation using functions

Tags: python, fibonacci-sequence

I know this code works, but is it correct to define them as functions or should I use something else?

```
import math

def Fibonnacci_sequence():
    i=int(input("How many numbers of the fibonnacci sequence do you want to see: "))
    a = 1
    b = 1
    n = 1
    print(a)
    print(b)
    n = n + 1 
    while n < i:
        c = a + b
        print(c)
        n = n + 1
        a = b
        b = c

def Fib_seqnum():
    i=int(input("What number of the fibonnacci sequence do you want to know: "))
    a = 1
    b = 1
    n = 1
    n = n + 1 
    while n < i:
        c = a + b
        n = n + 1
        a = b
        b = c
    print(c)

def solve_qaudratic():
    a=float(input("Enter A: "))
    b=float(input("Enter B: "))
    c=float(input("Enter C: "))
    d = (b*b) - 4*a*c
    if d < 0:
        print("No real roots")
    elif d == 0:
        x = -b/(2*a)
        print("equal roots" (x))
    else:
        x = math.sqrt(d)
        i = (-b -x)/(2*a)
        o = (-b +x)/(2*a)
        print("X1 = " (i))
        print("X2 = " (o))

print("Welcome to maths")
print("PRESS 1 TO LOOK AT THE FIBONNACCI SEQUENCE")
print("PRESS 2 TO SOLVE A QUADRATIC")
print("PRESS 9 TO EXIT")
answer=int(input("Enter Choice: " ))
if answer==1:
    Fibonnacci_sequence()
elif answer==2:
    solve_qaudratic()
elif answer==3:
    Fib_seqnum()
elif answer==9:
    exit()
else:
    print("WHAT?!")
```

Comment: Your `print()` calls in `solve_qaudratic()` aren't syntactically valid. Please ensure that the code works as posted.

Comment: it does work i have tested it

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tested it. `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: copy it i just did and it worked perfectly

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Fails as reported in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: `"X1 = " (i)` means to treat `i` as a parameter when calling the function `"X1 = "` — and of course the string is not a function.

Answer (score 4):

Your functions do too many things:

- get input from user
- do some calculation
- print result

It would be better to separate these responsibilities,
following the *single responsibility principle*.

When you separate these responsibilities, the Fibonacci generation logic will naturally end up in its own function, and the reusability becomes obvious.

Consider this rewrite of your `Fibonnacci_sequence` function:

```
def fib_sequence(n):
    """
    >>> fib_sequence(10)
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]

    :param n: the number of items to calculate
    :return: list of the first n items in the sequence
    """
    a = 1
    b = 1
    k = 2
    seq = [a, b]
    while k < n:
        c = a + b
        seq.append(c)
        k += 1
        a = b
        b = c

    return seq
```

The improvements:

- removed the printing
- removed the user input
- follows [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- better variable names
- documented
- has a doctest

The most interesting part is the doctest.
You can run doctests with the command:

```
python -m doctest script.py
```

Let's add a bunch more doctests:

```
>>> fib_sequence(0)
[]

>>> fib_sequence(1)
[1]

>>> fib_sequence(2)
[1, 1]

>>> fib_sequence(3)
[1, 1, 2]
```

And let's rerun the doctests. Which of these new tests will fail? `fib_sequence(0)` and `fib_sequence(1)` will fail. Just like your original implementation always printed the first two 1s, this one also always returns a list starting with `[1, 1, ...]`.
The good thing is that now that we have the tests, we can go ahead and confidently refactor the implementation.

As a matter of fact, a nice way to generate sequences in Python is using generators. Here's an implementation of the Fibonacci sequence using a generator:

```
def fib():
    yield 1
    yield 1
    prev = 1
    current = 1
    while True:
        prev, current = current, prev + current
        yield current
```

Now we can rewrite `fib_sequence` in terms of this new `fib` function:

```
it = fib()
return [next(it) for _ in range(n)]
```

If we rerun the doctests, now they all pass.
We can further simplify this implementation using `itertools.islice`:

```
return list(itertools.islice(fib(), 0, n, 1))
```

To finish up, let's rewrite `Fibonnacci_sequence` in terms of `fib_sequence`:

```
def fibonacci_sequence():
    n = int(input("How many numbers of the Fibonacci sequence do you want to see: "))
    for num in fib_sequence(n):
        print(num)
```

It's a lot cleaner isn't it.

I invite you to write a `fib_nth` method similarly, following the same logical steps we took for `fib_sequence`:

- remove the prompting and printing, make it return a value
- write doctests, for all the interesting cases
- rewrite `fib_nth` in terms of `fib`
- rewrite `fib_seqnum` in terms of `fib_nth`